# Count repeated words using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this exercise but i a little bit stuck, this is what i have right now, i am trying to iterate over the string incrementing the index plus one per word

> "Write a function to perform basic string compression using the counts
>   of repeated characters e.g "aabcccccaaa" would become "a2b1c5a3", if
>   the compressed string would not become smaller than the original, just
>   print the original"

```js
function countWords() {
  var word = "aabcccccaaa";
  var result = "";
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] != word[i + 1]) {
      result = result + word[i] + counter;
      counter = 0;
      i++;
    } else {
      counter++;
      i++;
    }
  }

  console.log(result);

  if (result.length < word.length)
    console.log(result)
  else
    console.log(word);
}

console.log(countWords())
```

Comment: Not a question. Define your problem.

Comment: _How_ isn't your code working? What part do you need help with?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can use the power of Regex, reduce in array and conditional ternary.

```
function compress(input) {
    var re = /(.)\1+|./gi;
    var match = input.match(re);
    var output = match.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + (currentValue.charAt(0) + currentValue.length);
    }, "");
    output = (output.length < input.length) ? output : input;
    return output;
}
console.log(compress("aabcccccaaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things going on.

First, you are incrementing your loop index twice.  Remove the `i++` from your `if` statement.

Secondly, you need to initialize your counter to 1 not 0.

This code seems to work.

```
<script>
function countWords()
    {
    var word = "aabcccccaaa";
    var result = "";
    var counter = 1;

    for(var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
        if(word.substr(i, 1) === word.substr(i+1, 1)) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            result = result + word.substr(i, 1) + counter;
            counter = 1;
        }
    }

    console.log(result);

    if(result.length < word.length)
        console.log(result)
    else
        console.log(word);
}

countWords();
</script>
```

Comment: I changed the logic from `!=` to `===` just to make it more clear to me but I think the other way would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function countChars(word) {
        if (!word) {
            return word;
        }
        var arr = word.split('');
        var currentChar = arr[0];
        var count = 1;
        var compression = "";
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === currentChar) {
                count++;
            } else {
                compression += currentChar + count;
                currentChar = arr[i];
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        compression += currentChar + count;
        
        if (compression.length > word.length) {
            return word;
        }
        return compression;
    }
    
    console.log(countChars("aabcccccaaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with reduce function:

```
let word = 'aabcccccaaa';
let chars = word.split('');
let counter = 1;
let occur = 0;

let result = chars.reduce(function(prevValue, currValue, index, array) {
  let isLastChar = array.length - 1 === index;

  if (prevValue.substr(prevValue.length - 1) !== currValue) {
    occur = counter;
    counter = 1;
    prevValue = prevValue + occur + currValue;
    return isLastChar ? prevValue + 1 : prevValue
  } else {
    counter++;
    return isLastChar ? prevValue + counter : prevValue;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with these bugs fixed.

1. `counter` starting at `0` so the count would be off by one.
2. similarly to `1)`, setting `counter` back to `0` each time instead of `1`.
3. incrementing `i` inside the for loop so values were being skipped.

```js
function countWords() {

  var word = "aabcccccaaa";
  var result = "";
  
  var counter = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] != word[i + 1]) {
      result = result + word[i] + counter;
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return result.length < word.length ? result : word;

}

console.log(countWords());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var inputString = "Javascript",
      searchChar, count = 0;
    accurancesRepeat(inputString);

    function accurancesRepeat(inputString) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
        searchChar = inputString[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < inputString.length; j++) {
          if (searchChar == inputString[j]) {
            count += 1;
          }
        }

        console.log("Accorances of character " + searchChar + " is... " + count);
        count = 0;
      }
    }
```